# Jupyter showing syntax error on match case, stating that i need pylance 3.10 or newer, which is already installed and working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, syntax-error, python-3.10, pylance

So, I've installed python 3.10.6 and everything works fine, even the match case where i get a syntax error works.
So even though all my code works fine and is valid, my editor still marks it as invalid syntax for some reason.

Any suggestions for how to fix this issue?

Image of the error message and results from successfully run code

[image: 1]

Comment: your python version is below 3.10. update it and set on interprete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently i just needed to go to extensions in VS-code and reload pylance...